# How do I tell if the returned cursor is the last cursor in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-cursor

I apologize if I am missing something really obvious.

I'm making successive calls to app engine using cursors.  How do I tell if the I'm on the last cursor?  The current way I'm doing it now is to save the last cursor and then testing to see if that cursor equals the currently returned cursor.  This requires an extra call to the datastore which is probably unnecessary though.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean "has this cursor hit the end of the search results", then no, not without picking the cursor up and trying it again. If more entities are added that match the original search criteria, such that they logically land "after" the cursor (e.g., a query that sorts by an ascending timestamp), then reusing that saved cursor will let you retrieve those new entities.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think there's a way to do this with ext.db in a single datastore call, but with [ndb](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) it is possible. Example:

```
query = Person.query(Person.name == 'Guido')
result, cursor, more = query.fetch_page(10)
```

If using the returned cursor will result in more records, `more` will be `True`. This is done smartly, in a single RPC call.

Comment: This doesn't seem particularly magic. All ndb is doing is asking for 11 results behind the covers when you ask for 10. If it got 11, then there is more. You can do the same trick with ext.db.

Comment: It's probably not magical, but do give NDB a try. It strikes me as a much better and more usable alternative.

Comment: @user103576 there's a little more than that. Try fetching 11 results with ext.db, use only 10 and then use the cursor to get more. You'll jump 1 result. It is not a secret, but the "magic" ndb does is to use a combination of `batch_size` and `limit` to request the cursor. ext.db doesn't expose these options in the query.

Answer (score 6):

Since you say 'last cursor' I assume you are using cursors for some kind of pagination, which implies you will be fetching results in batches with a `limit`.

In this case then you know you are on the last cursor when you have less results returned than your limit.

```
limit = 100
results = Entity.all().with_cursor('x').fetch(limit)
if len(results)<limit:
    # then there's no point trying to fetch another batch after this one
```

Comment: Not a perfect solution. If you have 30 records and a limit of 10, the 'last page' will have 10 records but if you use the cursor the result will be empty. So if your total records count is a multiple of limit, this logic won't apply.

Comment: True, it just makes the 'wasted' query the exception rather than the norm.

Answer (score 1):

I use the same technique Chris Familoe describes, but set the limit 1 more than I wish to return. So, in Chris' example, I would fetch 101 entities. 101 returned means I have another page with at least 1 on.

```
    recs = db_query.fetch(limit + 1, offset)

    # if less records returned than requested, we've reached the end
    if len(recs) < limit + 1:
        lastpage = True
        entries = recs
    else:
        lastpage = False
        entries = recs[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kind of old but I was looking for a solution to the same problem.  I found it in this excellent book:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920017547.do

Here is the tip:

```
    results = query.fetch(RESULTS_FOR_PAGE)

    new_cursor = query.cursor()
    query.with_cursor(new_cursor)
    has_more_results = query.count(1) == 1
```